# How can I publish a project to GitHub without my repository's version control history?

Tags: git, github, version-control, mercurial, open-source

I am looking into publishing an open-source project from an existing code base that I've developed. The code base has about 2000 revisions and I've been working on it for about a year. I recently developed an application that uses my existing source code as a base (I copy and pasted the Android project directory) and started coding away, not realizing that somehow the entire version control history is attached to it. When I uploaded it to a private Bitbucket repository, it also uploaded every other commit. Is there any way to easily remove the repository from my source code (I'm using Mercurial with TortoiseHg) before I publish my new open-source project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Copy all the files in a new repository (excluding `.hg` or `.git` folder)
2. init a new repository
3. commit them all.

You're done.